# Can MySQL INT type be non-zero NULL

Tags: mysql, null, int

I'm creating a MySQL DB which is composed of weekly data sets, going back for the past decade. There are some data points which exist for recent records, but which were not tracked in some of the older data sets. The fields in question all contain integer values, and '0' is a perfectly valid (and frequent) value for the records which did track the data points. I need to be able to distinguish between a value of zero and non-existent data. Therefore, I need to find out if it is possible to store a NULL which is not represented as a '0' (read: BLANK CELL) for an INT type. However, NULL values passed to the DB are represented as '0' (at least, they are in phpMyAdmin), is there any way to change this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should allow the column to contain null values. But the short answer is: yes, int columns can have NULL values.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the value to NULL. `INSERT INTO table (INT_COLUMN) VALUES (NULL)` is valid SQL (with INT_COLUMN being a nullable int column).

Comment: Ive tried passing the value as both blank "" and as NULL, and in both situations it shows as "0" (at least when browsing in PHPMyAdmin)...

Comment: Have you set the default value of the column to 0? Paste your table definition here.

Comment: improve your answer by adding definition of `nullable`

Comment: A nullable column accepts NULL as a valid value. `ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column int null;` should make the column accept null values.

Comment: Oh god, it's huge. Here is an example (I haven't specified a storage engine 'cus at the stage of development I am at I really haven't cared)- CREATE TABLE blah (week_code INT NOT NULL, value_x INT, value_y INT, ... , PRIMARY KEY(week_code)). Note, of course the problem I'm asking about isn't with the PK. However, in the PHPMyAdmin panel it lists the fields in question as being default NULL.

Comment: You know what guys, my queries are being dynamically generated from a PHP array. I would bet you anything the problem is in how the array is storing/passing the data to the query string. You answered my question though, in INT field can contain a NULL values. Sorry for being a dunce. Thanks for your time/help.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is "yes" - you can have nullable int columns. But should you?

Too often, `null` is misused and misunderstood. In SQL databases, `null` means "unknown". In your situation, using `null` is perfect, so "yes - you should"

There are cases when you want to use a specific value for "null", for example `-1` for a quantity. This approach is valid and is used to simplify the application code and SQL, because dealing with nulls in queries is a pain in the ass:

- You have to use the special syntax "IS NULL"
- Any list containing a null will never match *anything*, eg `WHERE NAME IN (SELECT COL1 FROM SOMETABLE)` will never work if any of the selected values is null
- Null doesn't equal anything else, even another null
- In strict (eg java) app code, you have a check that a value is null or you'll get a NullPointerException. Using an actual value avoids this

Comment: Using "magic" values may be good in certain case but it can also be a pain in the ass. A usual `SUM()` or `AVG()` will yield wrong results if you have some `-1` values in there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, be sure your table is designed to allow NULL values in the column in question.  See the very basic example below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testTable;
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `data` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;

INSERT INTO testTable VALUES
(NULL, 100),
(NULL, 200),
(NULL, NULL),
(NULL, 400);

SELECT * FROM testTable;
```

The select will have the following result:

```
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  1 |  100 |
|  2 |  200 |
|  3 | NULL |
|  4 |  400 |
+----+------+
```

Comment: Per the other comments here, if you could show us the output for the "show create table <tablename>" statement we could confirm whether or not your issue is with the table definition or not.